# inner join is breaking microservice rules?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I want to convert my monolith application to microservices.

I have two endpoints: `/reports` and `/companies`. each of them have CRUD ops following by REST ideas.

In the `reports/:id` I return the report with fields such id, title, body, lastUpdated and so on.

But I also need to return the companies that associate with this report.

So in my microservices application I create two services: `Report` and `Company`.

In the database I have Report table and Company table.

All of the reports I return from `Report` service or from `/reports/..` in my monolith application must return reports that contains at least one company.

This is means the each returns report I must do inner join with company table.

```
select * from report r inner join company c on c.id = r.id
```

So its end up with Report service is access to company table using inner join.

Using inner join to another table (that another service using it) is breaking the microservice rules?

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of microservices is loose coupling. Since a microservice should have its own bounded context, which implies that it should only manage and access the data model within its defined bounded context.

In your case, Report MS trying to access data in Company MS is actually a violation of this principle because you are bundling Report MS with Company MS.

To avoid it, you have 2 options:

1. storing copy: storing a copy of data that Report MS is going to read in its own DB. You can achieve this via event driven design with tools like kafka and CDC.
2. have an extra layer for aggregation: assume you will store the report and company mapping relationship in Report table, you can then have this extra MS to call Report MS for report definition and its company relationship, and then call Company MS with those company ids to return more info or check its validity, then aggregate to the result you want as response. To implement this layer, you may consider GraphQL.